# Correlated Subquery to determine Customer Records

Tags: mysql, sql, correlated-subquery

I have two tables, customer and customer_order

**Customer**

cust_id, cust_name
121 Acme Wholesalers
234 Griffen Electric
336 East Coast Marine Supplies
544 Sanford Automotive

**Customer_Orders**

order_num,cust_id,order_date
1   121 2019-01-15
2   234 2019-07-24
3   336 2020-05-02
4   121 2019-01-15
5   336 2020-03-19
6   234 2019-07-24
7   121 2019-01-15
8   336 2020-06-12

I need to write a query that returns the name of the customer who has placed exactly 3 orders. I cannot return the same customer name than once and I must use a correlated subquery against the customer_order table.

So far I have the following, which returns all four customers.

select c.cust_name
from customer c
where exists
(select count(*)
from customer_order co
where c.cust_id = co.cust_id);

I need to add the = 3 qualifier but not sure where.

Comment: Please try that code
select c.cust_name
from customer c
where cust_id IN (SELECT GROUP_CONACT(cust_id) FROM customer_order )

Comment: I ran the query and go no results.

Comment: Please run that code SELECT GROUP_CONACT(cust_id) FROM customer_order

Comment: I get the following: 121,234,336,121,336,234,121,336

Comment: Please run that code select c.cust_name from customer c where cust_id IN (121,234,336,121,336,234,121,336 )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select c.cust_name, count(co.id) as num_orders
from customer c join customer_order co on c.cust_id = co.cust_id
group by c.cust_name
having  num_orders = 3;
```

I am assuming, that `cust_name` is unique, else you must group by `cust_id`.